# angular6 ngx pagination message for records not showing properly

Tags: angular

I used ngx pagination on the list contains 330 records, I gave items for page as 10. But whenever page is loaded, it's showing message like **"showing 330 out of 330"** instead of  **"10 out of 330"**. So please can anyone suggest me the solution?

This my code:

```html
<div class="message">
  Showing : <b>{{tempAccountType?.length}}</b> Out of : <b>{{AccountType?.length}}</b> Records.
</div>
<div>
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageActual = $event" responsive="true" previousLabel="Previous" nextLabel="Next">
  </pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be an issue with  tempAccountType and AccountType. I guess both are having same values now(330 records).

Answer (score 0):

> The PaginatePipe should be placed at the end of an NgFor expression.
>   It accepts a single argument, an object conforming to the
>   PaginationInstance interface.

```
<div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate:  {
                currentPage: 1,
                itemsPerPage: 10}">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>
  <pagination-controls  
    (pageChange)="pageActual = $event" 
    responsive="true" 
    previousLabel="Previous" 
    nextLabel="Next">
  </pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pagination

For More Info Check the Doc:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination#paginatepipe